# How to handle multipart body request with x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I am using `Retrofit2`. I know that is only one encoding annotation is allowed. in retrofit. but I need to have all the attributes. `inqueue` in `body` and `id` in `path` while `x-www-form-urlencoded`

```
@Multipart
@FormUrlEncoded
@PUT("queue/{id}")
Call<Queue> cancelQueue(@Header("Authorization") String Authorization, @Path("id") String id, @Part("inqueue") RequestBody inqueue));
```

Note: I used postman in this way and it works.